# Why isn't this "if statement" working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, range

I have built a weather app that works perfectly. I decided to add in icons that change with the weather id variable from an API which has been assigned. It works for the first id in the if statement, but when I add else if statements inside it don't work for the else if parts here is my code:

```
       //weather icons check       
          if(weatherId=800){
             $('#type').css('background-image', 'url(http://publicdomainvectors.org/photos/weather-clear.png)');
          }
          else if(weatherId>=801 && weatherId<=804){
              $('#type').css('background-image','url(http://publicdomainvectors.org/tn_img/stylized_basic_cloud.png)');
          }
          else if(weatherId>=300 && weatherId<=531){
               $('#type').css('background-image','url(http://publicdomainvectors.org/tn_img/sivvus_weather_symbols_4.png)');
          }
```

am I missing something in this statement???

Comment: `weatherid = 800` is an assignment. Change it to `if(weatherId == 800){`

Comment: `weatherId=800`

Comment: `weatherid === 800` triple equal is best.

Comment: It IS working, it is just that the assignment in the conditional returns the assigned value 800 so for instance this alerts 800 `alert(weather=800);` and all positive integers are a "truthy" value in Javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You 've missed one equal symbol (=) in your first if. It should be like that:

```
if(weatherId==800){
   $('#type').css('background-image', 'url(http://publicdomainvectors.org/photos/weather-clear.png)');
}
else if(weatherId>=801 && weatherId<=804){
    $('#type').css('background-image','url(http://publicdomainvectors.org/tn_img/stylized_basic_cloud.png)');
}
else if(weatherId>=300 && weatherId<=531){
     $('#type').css('background-image','url(http://publicdomainvectors.org/tn_img/sivvus_weather_symbols_4.png)');
}
```

Comment: I just realized that. Thank you so much

Comment: @MikeL5799 you can accept the answer if this solved your issue :)

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
if(weatherId=800){
```

to

```
if(weatherId==800){
```

Notice the double ==

Comment: I just noticed it, thank you so much